# twig automatic convert string to day

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to convert a string value to day by tapping in a widget, e.g.  `24` → `1`

```
{% block convert_day %}
    <td>{{ form_widget(form['crush']) }}</td>
    <td><!-- displaying my value in day --></td>
{% endblock %}
```

---

No It doesn't work !

To be more clear ,I want to do something like that but just display number of days : http://www.convertworld.com/en/time/Days.html

Comment: Example I put 24 in the widget it displays 1 day , if I put 23 it displays 0,96 day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's what I did ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function execute_time_ext(clicked) {
if (document.forms && document.forms['show_convert']) {
var from = document.forms['show_convert'].unit_from.value;
var elms = document.getElementsByName('unit');
var amount = document.forms['show_convert']['value'].value;
var to;
var amount_int = ['show_convert']['value'] - 0;
for (var i=0; i<elms.length; i++) {
to = elms[i].value;
convert(show_convert['value'], from, to, false, false);
}
var cookie = 'default_decimals';
if (getCookie(cookie) != decimals) {
setCookie(cookie, decimals, null, '/');
}
} else {
if (clicked) {
alert('Converter error. Conversion not supported by browser.');
}
}
}
execute_time_ext(false);

</script>
```

widget :

```
<div onkeyup="execute_time_ext(true)" onchange="execute_time_ext(true)"> {{ form_widget(form['value']) }} {% endblock %}

                                <div> <input id="value_4" type="hidden" value="365.25|0|4" name="unit"></div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ hourValue / 24 }}
```

Or, if you want to round the value to two decimal places:

```
{{ hourValue / 24 | number_format(2, ".", ",") }}
```

Documentation:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html

*edit*

Alternatively, you can put the precision into the form instance itself. When you create your form, you're probably doing something like this in your controller (or if the form has its own class, you're doing something similar in the `buildForm()` method of that class):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->getForm();
```

When you add your `crush` field, you can then specify the number of decimal places that should be represented on the form by including the `precision` option:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('crush', 'number', array('precision' => 3) )
    ->getForm();
```

The form will then round the value before inserting it into the database.

Documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#precision

Comment: But I want to display this in the same time that I put the value in the widget , I think it's possible with ajax or javascript?!

Comment: I've edited my response with a different answer that addresses your concern.

Comment: Ok , I will test it and tell you the result

Comment: No It doesn't work !

To be more clear ,I want to do something like that but just display number of days : http://www.convertworld.com/en/time/Days.html